# Imagick Commandline flip image

Tags: php, imagemagick

i want to convert !

[image]

using imagick commandline operation

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Imagemagick command line, use `tile:` & `mpr:` [file formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php), and [-flip](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#flip), [-clone](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clone), & [-append](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append) options.

```
convert face.png -scale 50x -flip \( -clone 0 -flip \) -append \
        -write mpr:tileflip +delete -size 200x200  \
        tile:mpr:tileflip output.png
```

[image]